# Paypal OAuth Implementation to onboard merchants on our site

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We have an app where we want to onboard Merchants to connect their Paypal account and then they can accept money from the customers directly through our webapp. I read through the docs and am a little lost on how to start.

What I understood is :
Using this document [Paypal Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/permissions/) we first need to generate authorization code then generate refresh and access token. But this document is for Paypal Here.

Also on the Customer Side should I use Smart Buttons [Doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#) where I can generate the order Id and execute the capture step on the Server side using the access token generated for the Merchants in the first part.

Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also need to do things like manage refunds via the API, have the merchants generate a REST client ID and secret via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications and copy this information into your configuration interface

If you don't need to do that, you can integrate PayPal Checkout with your own API credentials, and set a 'payee' object, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

Comment: When clients share their ID and secret doesn’t that give us all the permissions ?

In your second approach of payee object - is there a way to get merchant id via API ? Like the OAuth way

Comment: It does indeed, that's the point. You can integrate a Connect with PayPal button, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/

Comment: Preston PHX : can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206572/revoke-paypal-access-within-paypal-and-from-our-app